# How do you write an <xs:unique> constraint correctly and/or get lxml to throw an exception when such a constraint is violated?

Tags: python, xml, xsd, lxml

I'm trying to figure out how `<xs:unique>` constraints work, and as part of that, I thought it would be worthwhile to see if I can create some XML that violates an `<xs:unique>` constraint in its associated schema. So I have this schema in `schema.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:element name="parent">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">

                <xs:element name="child">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:attribute name="foo" type="xs:string" />
                    </xs:complexType>
                    <xs:unique name="someUniqueConstraint">
                        <xs:selector xpath="child" />
                        <xs:field xpath="@foo" />
                    </xs:unique>
                </xs:element>

            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

And this document in `data.xml`:

```xml
<parent>
    <child foo="1" />
    <child foo="2" />
    <child foo="2" />
</parent>
```

I'm doing validation with Python's `lxml` library, which is a binding for `libxml2`:

```python
from lxml import etree

# load and parse schema and xml
with open('schema.xml', 'r') as f:
    schema_root = etree.parse(f)
with open('data.xml', 'r') as f:
    data_root = etree.parse(f)

schema = etree.XMLSchema(schema_root)
schema.assertValid(data_root)
```

My expectation is that the validation code above should raise an exception on the `schema.assertValid` line, since the uniqueness constraint on the `foo` attribute of `<child>` tags is being violated. However, this doesn't happen - the assertion succeeds.

I'm guessing that either 1.) I've written the `<xs:unique>` constraint incorrectly; or 2.) `lxml` and/or `libxml2` does not actually do uniqueness validation. Either way, what should I do differently to get `lxml` to enforce a uniqueness constraint such that it does *not* treat the document above as valid?

(I've managed to get validation errors out of `lxml` from various other schema violations, so it's not that my install of `lxml` is broken or anything.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I just had the `<xs:unique>` constraint in the wrong place.

It should've been:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:element name="parent">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">

                <xs:element name="child">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:attribute name="foo" type="xs:string" />
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>

            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>

        <xs:unique name="someUniqueConstraint">
            <xs:selector xpath="child" />
            <xs:field xpath="@foo" />
        </xs:unique>

    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

i.e. with the constraint moved to the parent element rather than the child element. Which makes sense, I guess, since, per https://stackoverflow.com/a/8806512/1535629 (which I'm going to vote-to-close as a duplicate of), the point is to enforce uniqueness among all children of a parent, so we ought to place the constraint at the parent level, so that it "knows" what constraints need to be enforced. With this change to `schema.xml`, the validator does throw an error:

> lxml.etree.DocumentInvalid: Element 'child': Duplicate key-sequence ['2'] in unique identity-constraint 'someUniqueConstraint'., line 4